# Check if the imageView has a drawable

Tags: android, imageview, android-drawable

```
if (image.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(0).getConstantState())){
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

That is, if image has not any drawable, image will be GONE, else Visible. But this code does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the getDrawable function on the image view and check if it is not null - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16445086/1649353

Answer (score 3):

> Try below may be it works for you(It's work for me)

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    if (image.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(image.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow_round_white).getConstantState())){

       image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else{
       image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

 }
else {
    if (image.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shadow_round_white).getConstantState())){
       image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    else{
       image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (image.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
            (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable).getConstantState()){//set here your drawable name(your_drawable)
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact, there is another way to compare:

```
if(imageView.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals
            (getResources().getDrawable(/*Your drawable*/).getConstantState()))
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(imageview.getDrawable()==null)
    {
      //if Image View is Null 
    }
```

check [source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#getDrawable%28%29)